# Problems with code to pull data from website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have [this website](https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/wedding-planners-acworth-ga?page=2) and I would like to pull via Python all company names such as `West Wood Events`, or `Mitchell Event Planning`.

But I am stuck on `soup.find` since it results me `[]`.
When I inspect the page, lets say this:

```
< div class="LinesEllipsis  vendor-name--55315 primaryBold--a3d1e body1--24afd">Mitchell Event Planning<wbr></div >
```

in that I would write:

```
week = soup.find(class_='LinesEllipsis  vendor-name--55315 primaryBold--a3d1e body1--24afd')

print(week)
```

And I get `0`.

Am I missing something? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: if you want to pull all company name use `soup.find_all` and read about soup library from this link [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the undesired behavior you're seeing

Comment: first check HTML which you get from server - it may send different HTML for different devices  (deskotp, tablet, phones) and for devices which don't use JavaScript. It can also send warning or captcha for bots/scripts.

Comment: you can also try CSS selector with dot for every class in string - `select('.LinesEllipsis.vendor-name--55315.primaryBold--a3d1e.body1--24afd')`

Comment: better show minimal working code which we could run and test ideas to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This string is not single class but many classes separated by spaces.

In some modules you would have to use original string with all spaces but it seems  in BS you have to use classes separated by single space.

---

Code works for me if I uses single space between `LinesEllipsis` and `vendor-name--55315`.

```
week = soup.find_all(class_='LinesEllipsis vendor-name--55315 primaryBold--a3d1e body1--24afd')
```

Or if I use CSS selector with dot for every class in string

```
week = soup.select('.LinesEllipsis.vendor-name--55315.primaryBold--a3d1e.body1--24afd')
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.theknot.com/marketplace/wedding-planners-acworth-ga?page=2'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')

#week = soup.select('.LinesEllipsis.vendor-name--55315.primaryBold--a3d1e.body1--24afd')
week = soup.find_all(class_='LinesEllipsis vendor-name--55315 primaryBold--a3d1e body1--24afd')

for item in week:
    print(item.text)
```

Result:

```
The Charming Details
Enraptured Events
pearl and sky events - planning, design and florals
Unique Occasions ByTNicole, Inc
Platinum Eventions
RED COMPANY ATLANTA
Pop + Fizz: Event Planning and Design
Patricia Elizabeth, certified wedding planners/producer
Rienza Events
Pollyanna Richter Weddings
Calabash Events, Inc.
Weddings by Carmona LLC
Emily Jordan Events
Perfectly Taylored Events
Lindsey Wise Designs
Elegant Weddings and Affairs
Party PLANit
Wedded Bliss
Above the Fray
Willow Jaymes Events
Coco Red Events
Liz D. Events, LLC
Leslie Cox Events
YSE LLC
Marmaros Productions
PerfectionsID, LLC
All Things Love
West Wood Events
Everlasting Elegance
Prestigious Occasions
```

Comment: Yes, I made similar code but your's kinda provides me correct spelling (&amp, was my problem :( )

Now I have issue with executing loop, I am using this method for first time so here is my code so far:

Comment: if you have new problem then create new question on new page. You will have more space for code, error message and explanation. And code will be formatted.